# src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ds:Signature' to an 'element declaration' component

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I want to do schema validation using an XSD file. When I import the XSD file to Eclipse, without running the validation class, I have the following error:

> src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ds:Signature' to an 'element
>   declaration' component

I am kinda new to XML vs XSD validation process.  Although I have looked for similar questions on google, I couldn't figure out what's wrong here.

The XSD file is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org"
        xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
        xmlns:abc="http://abc.123.com" targetNamespace="http://abc.123.com"
        xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" elementFormDefault="qualified"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
        <xs:import namespace="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" schemaLocation="XAdES.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" schemaLocation="XAdESv141.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="headerType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="doorNumber" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

How should I modify the XSD to fix this error?

Comment: Um... Take the `ds:` out of the `ref`, or add a schema for `ds` as you have `xs`. (You have to actually read both the error message and the XSD. Three lines up from the bottom.)

Comment: perhaps that the element Signature does not exist in the schema "xmldsig-core-schema.xsd". notice that xml is case sensitive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**If** you have `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` in the same directory as your XSD, **and if** it is the same as [this XSD](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd), then you should not be getting an error about a failure to resolve `ds:Signature`.

Therefore, I suspect that your import is failing, and you're missing or ignoring a warning such as the following:

> [Warning] try.xsd:9:56: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema
>   document 'xmldsig-core-schema.xsd', because 1) could not find the
>   document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of
>   the document is not `<xsd:schema>`.

Try this XSD as a test; it loads directly from the URL for `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
           xmlns:abc="http://abc.123.com"
           targetNamespace="http://abc.123.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
             schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
  <xs:complexType name="headerType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="doorNumber" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I've tested the above XSD and found that it eliminates the resolution error that you were seeing.

Comment: updating signature schema location with the URL seems to work.I don't have the error anymore.thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you can cache locally the `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd`, put it in the same directory of your xsd schema, an then let your original

```
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
```

This will resolve your problem of importing a file from W3C website and save time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

I just generated XSD files from cXML DTD files using Visual Studio 2019 and ran into the same problem.

In my case solution contained multiple steps:

1. Save digital signature schema file `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` (downloadable from https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd) in the same folder as you cXML schema files
2. Search for & replace all the occurrences of `xmlns:ds="uri:ds"` with `xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"`
3. Find & delete all the occurances of `<xs:import namespace="uri:ds" />`

After these steps cXML schema files validated and I was able to generate C# classes using command:

`xsd /c cXML.xsd xmldsig-core-schema.xsd`

**Note:** `xsd` tool requires both schemas to be passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the .xsd file by modifying the line:

```
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and in order not to open another thread, I will contribute with more information.
I need to validate an XDocument against a schema that has schemas linked to it.

This is my validation code:

```
XmlSchemaSet schema = new();
schema.Add("http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte", "EnvioDTE_v10.xsd");
xDocument.Validate(schema, ValidationEventHandler!);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlsetdte);
doc.Validate(
schema,
   (o, e) =>
  {
       Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
  }
     );
  doc.Validate(schema, ValidationEventHandler!);
```

This is the main xsd:
[image: main xsd]

The second xsd:

[image: second xsd]

and third:

[image: third xsd]

all the xsd files are in the app path, i have also tried to change "schemaLocation" as suggested in this thread: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924686/src-resolve-cannot-resolve-the-name-dssignature-to-an-element-declaration) but nothing has worked for me.

Which xsd should I modify?
This is the error code:
[image: exception]